# Python 3.7.1 findall() not behaving as expected

Tags: python, findall

First of all, I know that this is not the current version of Python and that the behavior of findall() was changed from 3.6. I don't believe either of those are issue I'm experiencing. And I haven't been able to find anything about findall() that has changed since 3.7.

I have already devised a fix using sub() instead of findall(), but I'm curious why I had to in the first place.

I have a function that is supposed to check for the presence of a pattern. If found, it's supposed to verify that the pattern has been previously defined. It looks like this at present (with the fix and some debug code):

```
    def _verifyargs(i, end, args):
        '''verify text replacement args'''

        def _findallfix(m):
            formals.append( m.group().upper() )
            return '-xxx- '
            
        # put any formal arguments into a more convenient form for checking

        checkargs = args.keys()
        print( f'checkargs: start={i}, end= {end}, args= {checkargs}' )

        # if there aren't any formal arguments we're still checking for
        # their improper use within the definition body

        while i < end:
            i, text = SRC.fetch( i+1 )
            SRC.setmaster( i )
            formals = []
            text = re.sub( SYM.macLabel, _findallfix, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE )
#           formals = re.findall( SYM.macLabel, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE )
            print( f'line= {i}, formals= {formals}' )
            for formal in formals:
#               formal = formal.upper()
                if not formal in checkargs:
                    UM.undefined( formal )

        SRC.setmaster(end)
```

The pattern looks like this:

```
SYM.macLabel = '[?][_A-Z]([.]?[_A-Z0-9])*'              # straight text replacement
```

When run against this piece of test code:

[image: part of test 100]

It produces this output:

[image: desired output (working)]

Which is fine. It's what I want. But if I comment out the fix:

```
    def _verifyargs(i, end, args):
        '''verify text replacement args'''

        def _findallfix(m):
            formals.append( m.group().upper() )
            return '-xxx- '
            
        # put any formal arguments into a more convenient form for checking

        checkargs = args.keys()
        print( f'checkargs: start={i}, end= {end}, args= {checkargs}' )

        # if there aren't any formal arguments we're still checking for
        # their improper use within the definition body

        while i < end:
            i, text = SRC.fetch( i+1 )
            SRC.setmaster( i )
#           formals = []
#           text = re.sub( SYM.macLabel, _findallfix, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE )
            formals = re.findall( SYM.macLabel, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE )
            print( f'line= {i}, formals= {formals}' )
            for formal in formals:
                formal = formal.upper()
                if not formal in checkargs:
                    UM.undefined( formal )

        SRC.setmaster(end)
```

...then the test produces this:

[image]

So findall() seems to be making an unexpected match, even though my understanding is that sub() and findall() should have exactly the same matching behavior.

Perhaps I'm abusing sub(). In this instance I don't care at all about the result of the substitution (I save it here only because I might want to look at it), but only that it finds the patterns I expect. Is there something I'm overlooking about the way findall() works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TL;DR

Use `(?: ... )` instead of `( ... )` because `re.findall` is giving you the capturing group instead of the whole matches.

##### Details

This question puzzled me for a bit, but I found the problem.

The [documentation for `re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.findall) says:

> The result depends on the number of capturing groups in the pattern.
> If there are no groups, return a list of strings matching the whole
> pattern. If there is exactly one group, return a list of strings
> matching that group. If multiple groups are present, return a list of
> tuples of strings matching the groups. Non-capturing groups do not
> affect the form of the result.

Since you have one set of parentheses, you have one captugin group, and that's what `re.findall` is returning. It matches what you expect, it just doesn't return what you thought it would.

By using non-capturing parentheses, `(?: ... )` you will get the results you want: the whole matches.

I.e.:

```
SYM.macLabel = '[?][_A-Z](?:[.]?[_A-Z0-9])*'
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized a bit after posting this (naturally) that it must have something to do with the parentheses in the pattern forming a capture group, but not how to do anything about it. Now that you've explained how to prevent it, all should be good! Thanks again!